# 21.5 inch retina iMac used as external monitor

Tags: display, imac

I am thinking of purchasing this little fella http://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/imac?product=MK452LL/A&step=config# and (also) using it as an external monitor to my MacBook Pro (mid 2014).

Is it possible?

Comment: @Allan That apple support page states that it`s possible only with certain iMacs.

Comment: Then, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the sense you can share the screen over a internet connection. There will be a noticeable small delay as information is exchanged over the internet connection. What you would normally see on the iMac is the same as seen on the Mac Book Pro. **The displays would mirror each other**. If you had an actually external monitor connected to the Mac Book Pro and you are not mirroring the displays, then what you would see on the single iMac display is what is shown on both the internal and external Mac Book Pro displays. So in this case, the iMac would mirror both the internal and external Mac Book Pro displays.

No, in the sense of an actual external monitor. There is no input jack on the iMac like you would find on an actual external monitor.

Other than this, I do think it is possible for you to buy another computer.

Comment: Could you point me to the guide on how to extend the screen over internet connection?

Comment: I updated my answer. I am not sure what you meant by extend. I you wanted to use the iMac as second display, you will not be able to do so. What is shown on the iMac internal display is exactly the same as shown on the Mac Book Pro internal display (Of course, the resolution may be different.) If you **wanted** to mirror the two computer displays, I can post how to do that.